# How to find out and replace String with Nested Array in CSV using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I have a requirement as need to load the CSV and find & replace string with nested array using Databricks with scala.
Can you please help me on this.

Regards,
Ram

Comment: Sample data and expected results please.  Plus include what you’ve tried already.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! A good question has a better chance of getting a good answer. :-) You may want to have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask